# In Room and Kotlin, can you set a @PrimaryKey with a different name?

Tags: kotlin, android-room

I'd like something like below. Is that possible?

```
@Entity(tableName = "cached_objects")
data class CachedObject(
    @PrimaryKey(name = "my_object_key") val myObjectKey: String
    val name: String
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's what `@ColumnInfo` is for:

```
@Entity(tableName = "cached_objects")
data class CachedObject(
    @PrimaryKey @ColumnInfo(name = "my_object_key") val myObjectKey: String
    val name: String
)
```

[Documentation here](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/defining-data#anatomy)